# How to turn off the dictionary in tess4j?

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

The accuracy of character recognition in my tess4j OCR application is very low. I have heard that turning off the dictionary in tess4j will increase the accuracy by letting individual characters to be recognized. But i don't know how to do it. Anyone know how to turn off the dictionary in tess4j?

Comment: Hi did you solve the problem? I have almost the same problem which I want to use Regex in order to improve the accuracy of the recognition, for example the text in image is fixed text `\d\d\w\w\d\d`, how can do it in tessertact in Java

Answer (score 2):

As follows:

```
TessBaseAPISetVariable(handle, "load_system_dawg", "F");
TessBaseAPISetVariable(handle, "load_freq_dawg", "F");
```

or

```
setTessVariable("load_system_dawg", "F");
setTessVariable("load_freq_dawg", "F");
```

**Update**:

Put the following in a file named, for example, `bazaar` placed under `configs` folder:

```
load_system_dawg     F
load_freq_dawg       F
```

and then pass the name of the file to the appropriate method:

```
List<String> configs = Arrays.asList("bazaar");
instance.setConfigs(configs);
```

References:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc
http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-1.4/

Comment: I think you also have to provide empty user_words_suffix and user_pattern_suffix files

Comment: Where is this `TessBaseAPISetVariable ` coming from? What package?